# Живой поиск по Яндекс карте

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Здравствуйте!
Я пытаюсь сделать поиск по Яндекс-карте без нажатия кнопки "искать" т.е. при вводе должен осуществляться поисковый запрос.
Поведение, которое я хочу реализовать, представлено на странице Яндекс карт: https://yandex.ru/maps

У меня получилось, но возникла проблема: не полностью написанные адреса автоматически исправляются на правильные в поле поиска, что довольно неудобно, если ты печатаешь с мобильного телефона. 
Чтобы было понятно, о чем я говорю, создал пример в песочнице: 
http://jsbin.com/biqihiq
Попробуйте ввести любой адрес (например, Комсомольский проспект). Полностью набрать его не получится, т.к. адрес будет автоматически исправлен на "правильный".
Я хочу, чтобы текст в поле поиска не исправлялся. 
Как добиться такого поведения? 
Или лучше реализовать живой поиск по-другому? Как?

Закомментированный кусок кода внизу -- мое решение проблемы: просто при загрузке результатов вручную менять "исправленный" адрес на тот, что был введен. Оно работает, но, по-моему это слишком костыльное решение. По нему тоже есть вопрос: как получить ссылку на элемент input поиска? Как мне кажется обращение к нему через css-селектор -- не самое правильное решение. Как можно грамотно поменять введенное значение в поле поиска? 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

На Яндекс.Картах это не "живой поиск", а поисковые подсказки - `suggest`. Просто там сделана кастомная вёрстка подсказок. Поиск происходит так же как в API - по нажатию кнопки "Найти".

Делать настоящие поисковые запросы при частичном вводе плохая практика, во-первых, так очень быстро закончится лимит бесплатного использования, во-вторых, результат поиска всегда будет "исправлен" и отформатирован иначе.

Кстати, по умолчанию в стандартной поисковой строке API включены поисковые подсказки, то есть ничего специально делать не надо.

[Подробнее в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/suggest-docpage/?from=SO)

[Пример на поисковые подсказки во внешнем поле ввода](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/suggest?from=SO)